# I need a text box on selecting other option in dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have created a dropdown list in which the values has to fetched from array. In those values I have a "other" option. On selecting other option I need a text box to appear using java script

Comment: Simple! you can write a function and onchange you can call the function from other to create a input and send it to DOM

Comment: Hi flora, welcome to SO.  Please take a tour of the help centre and in particular [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)